# temporarily change pandas’ set_option for displaying dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Jupyter notebook and imported many `DataFrames` and one of them contains very long strings. Thus, I'd like to temporarily change `pandas`' display option without affect the global setting. I tried to use `with`:

```
with pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 220): 
    df.head()
```

But it doesn't work and returns `AttributeError: __enter__.`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### [**`pandas.option_context`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html)

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 220):
  print(df.head())
```

---

Consider `d1`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['brown', 'blue', 'blue'*20]))

print(d1)

                                                   A
0                                              brown
1                                               blue
2  bluebluebluebluebluebluebluebluebluebluebluebl...
```

You can see the column width is not long enough

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 220):
  print(d1.head())                                                           

    A
0                                                                             brown
1                                                                              blue
2  blueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblueblue
```

---

To show the HTML

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 220):
  display(HTML(d1.to_html()))
```

[image]

Comment: The `print()` function prints each row as plain text instead of displaying a dataframe. This display has no difference than just using `.values_counts()` .

Comment: The `print` was just an example.  Your question was in regards to how to temporarily set options.  `pandas.option_context` is how you do that.

Comment: @Steven, I think what you want is to use _display_ instead of print of just df. By using this you will get Jupyter famous dataframe style.