# Change appearance of pandas df in jupyer notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to have a look at a pandas df in jupyter notebook. However this is how it looks:

[image]

How can I achieve that the values in the first 6 columns are shown in one line just as the values in the columns at the end of my dataframe? I already tried

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth",  100)
pd.set_option("display.width",  100)
```

But they don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by doing:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 220):
  display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

For more information about `.option_context()` from official site visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html)

This answer is picked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472270/temporarily-change-pandas-set-option-for-displaying-dataframe), visit there for more information about answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me.

Comment: @thyhmoo what does that mean? Haven't you saw the edited answer?

Comment: Thanks for your help! But again even with the edit it stays the same as above

Comment: No it's still not changing anything